# SOAP Authentication with Certificate in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap, wsdl

I need to authenticate to a SOAP server using a certificate.

I created a SOAP client in Visual Studio / C# using "Add Service Reference" to import a .wsdl file, now I'm able to use the service class soap.ServiceReference1.SerWSPortClient. 
Using mmc.exe I added the certificate to both local computer and current user.
I am able to find the certificate and add it to the client class but when I call a service method I get an SSL error.

This is my code:

```
    soap.ServiceReference1.SerWSPortClient client = new soap.ServiceReference1.SerWSPortClient();

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline;

    soap.ServiceReference1.ResponseGetList list;
    list = client.getList();
```

And here is the error:

```
 System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'ser.ver.com'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately I don't have access to the server code.

I'm thinking that maybe I need to add some extra info to the client class in order for the authentication to succeed. The client I'm writing this code for tells me he had to use a security card and he had to input a PIN code to access the server url in browser (eg. http://ser.ver.com/api/wsdl? ) in order to retrieve the wsdl file he gave me. When he tried to run my code he got the same error as I did. I have neither the card nor the PIN code and when I try to navigate to the server url I get this error, although I added the certificate manually for chrome.

`ser.ver.com didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.
Try contacting the system admin.
ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`

Comment: that's the server rejecting the certificate that you submitted as a client. System.net just throws more generic errors than chrome does. unfortunately. I get it when I submit a revoked certificate